# YOLO training by own dataset

Tags: python, model, yolo

I have trained a [YOLO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_detection#Methods) model with my own dataset. After training, how can I get my **.weights** file?

Since I need to share my model with others, I need the **.weights file**. Or is there another way to share the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't make any modification. The weights file is stored inside the backup folder  `darknet\backup\`

Answer (score 0):

The code you used to train shall give you the weights you need. Search for the **.weight** files as the code help tells you.